# Laravel 5 Model Accessor Displayed as Undefined Variable

Tags: laravel-5, accessor

I have the following laravel model class and I have an accessor to get the location name as follows (not sure if its correct syntax)

```
class Job extends Model {

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
    }

    public function getLocationNameAttribute()
    {
         return $this->location('name');
    }

}
```

in my form I have the following:

```
{!! Form::text('location_name', $locationname !!}
```

But I get error Undefined variable: locationname when i try to view the page.

The location table has two columns(id, name) and I want to get the name of the location associated with the job. How do you do this. In the job table I only store the location_id.  I can do it as follows `isset($job->location_id) ? $job->location->name : ''` but I'm trying to understand how I can achieve the same using an accessor. Can any one shed some light please.